# Inserting Values into Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I Select * From my sql table in PHP, and I convert it to JSON, so the results are like this:

```
([
    {"id":"350","Name":"BlaBla","Info":"BlaBla"}, 
    {"id":"351","Name":"BlaBla","Info":"BlaBla"},
    {"id":"352","Name":"BlaBla","Info":"BlaBla"}
]);
```

I scrape a clients website for images (this is a request of the client) based on the id in the records above, and I output images into a similar array/dictionary and output into JSON:

```
([
    {"image1":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"},
    {"image2":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"},
    {"image3":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"},
    {"image4":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"},
    {"image5":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"}
]);
```

So lets say I scrape a page, `page.php?id=350`, I'd get a similar output to the image array above, how can I append/add that result to the first array where `id=350`?

**EDIT**

This is where I would like to combine the arrays:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) 
                    { 
    $rows[] = $row;
    $url = 'http://www.url.com/page.php?id='.$row['id'].'';
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    foreach($html->find('div.classvalue') as $element){
    foreach($element->find('img') as $img){

      $images[] = array("image".$i."" => $img->src);
      $i = $i + 1;
      $rows = array_merge($rows, $images);

} } }
```

My version clearly does not work, it seems to be appending new images to the already existing image[] therefore the last element of $rows[] will get the full list of images, where I just want the images tied in with that id. 
Also by merging, it does not merge correctly I get an output like this e.g:

```
([
    {"id":"350","Name":"BlaBla","Info":"BlaBla"},
    {"image1":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"},
    {"image2":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"}, 
    {"id":"351","Name":"BlaBla","Info":"BlaBla"}
]);
```

I would like it like:

```
([
    {"id":"350","Name":"BlaBla","Info":"BlaBla", "image1":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg", "image2":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"} etc...
]);
```

Comment: don't do it to the json string. do it to whatever structure you used to CREATE the json - e.g. don't convert to json until you're done. stay with native php arrays/objects until right before the end.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, converting to JSON is the last line of my file.  I'm trying to do this in the while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){}.  $rows[] is my table data $images[] is my images (obvious), when i pass a query manually It's fine, but in this loop it's incorrect

Comment: where is the closing `}` for the first for loop?

Comment: } = not a problem, I just did not copy and paste it on here, but I'll do so now.

Comment: @MikeJ There's actually two closing `}` missing. Please check your code because you really need to close a for loop after you've opened it...

Comment: @rednaw - IN my php they are there, I just did not Copy and Paste them over to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. You first have to start with a clean `$images` array using `$images = array();` so you won't have the results of previous loops in your array. Then you should collect the images inside the `$images` array (using the forloops). Then you can store the images in the `$row` array under the key `'images'` using `$row['images'] = $images;`.

Hope this is what you need.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { 

    $url = 'http://www.url.com/page.php?id='.$row['id'].'';
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $images = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($html->find('div.classvalue') as $element){

        foreach($element->find('img') as $img){
            $row["image".$i] = $img->src;    
            $i = $i + 1;    
        }

    }

    $rows[] = $row;

}
```

Comment: It's really getting close now, needs 1 more fix.  The results I get now is:

`([{"id":350","Name":"BlaBla","Info":"BlaBla","images":{[{"image1":"imgsource"}]})` is it possible to have the images stored within the record dictionary?

Comment: I changed the code. Note that I now also added `$i = 0;`, otherwise the counter for your images will not be reset for each row.

Answer (score 0):

On php side use **array_merge()** with both arrays. In addition array_unique will become handy (it will remove duplicates).

Comment: That will just merge both,  I want to add the results of the image array to a specific row in the first array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `$images` to the actual row. What you are doing, is resizing array.

```
$actualIndex = count($rows);
$rows[] = $row;
...
...
$rows[$actualIndex] = $images;
```

Or something like this

You can tweak `$rows[$actualIndex]` to satisfy your structure.
First set somewhere `$imageID = 1`;

```
$rows[$actualIndex]['image'.$imageID] = $images['url']
imageID++;
```

Comment: Tried this, but not quite there, the results I get are:   

`({"0":{"id":350, "Name":"BlaBla","Info":"BlaBla"},"17":[{"image1":"http://Sourceofimg.jpg"}]});`